# How to change text onclick using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are multiple rows like

Name    status

a          YES (hyperlink)
b          NO  (hyperlink)
c          YES (hyperlink)

My Code is:

```
function change_text() {
  var button = document.getElementById('toggle_button');
  if (button.innerHTML === "YES") {
      button.innerHTML = "NO";
  }
  else {
      button.innerHTML = "YES";
  }
}
```

```
<a href='javascript: toggle()'><p id="toggle_button" onclick="change_text()">YES</p></a>
 <a href='javascript: toggle()'><p id="toggle_button" onclick="change_text()">NO</p></a> 
<a href='javascript: toggle()'><p id="toggle_button" onclick="change_text()">YES</p></a>
```

onclick its happening for first row only kindly provide some solution. I am new on javascript or stackoverflow. in case any question please do the comment.

Comment: you can convert these ID's into class.

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same `id`. All of those `<p>` tags have the same id of `toggle_button`.

Comment: @radhikadev, I strongly encourage you to review my response. It's evident you're either A) very new to JavaScript, or B) following some very old tutorials.

Comment: yes micek i am new to js. i am learning it by doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's probably how I'd do it

[jsbin.com demo](http://jsbin.com/EhIpaVi/3/edit)

```js
// define Toggler "class"
var Toggle = function(elem) {

  elem.addEventListener("click", onClick);

  function onClick(event) {
    toggleText();
    event.preventDefault(); 
  }

  function toggleText() {
    var text = elem.innerHTML;
    elem.innerHTML = (text === "YES") ? "NO" : "YES"; 
  }

  this.toggle = toggleText;
};

// initialize
var toggles = document.getElementsByClassName("toggle");

for (var i=0, len=toggles.length; i<len; i++) {
  new Toggle(toggles[i]);
}
```

This would **unobtrusively** attach to HTML elements with class `toggle`

```html
<a href="#toggle" class="toggle">YES</a>
<a href="#toggle" class="toggle">NO</a>
<a href="#toggle" class="toggle">YES</a>
```

As an added convenience, this `Toggle` "class" provides an API for you to programmatically interact with your togglers

```html
<a href="#toggle" id="foo">YES</a>
```

```js
// API example
var elem = document.getElementById("foo");
var fooToggle = new Toggler(elem);

// toggle off
fooToggle.toggle();
// <a href="#toggle" id="foo">NO</a>

// toggle on again
fooToggle.toggle();
// <a href="#toggle" id="foo">YES</a>
```

---

Now, since this isn't changing `inputs` or anything, you might want to use `data-value="YES"` or `data-value="NO"` on the `a` elements. Then when you submit the page, you could collect this data, convert it to JSON, then submit it for processing.

Answer (score 0):

id is always uniq.you can't use multiple time same id.Please differentiate the id and try.

```
<script>
function change_text(obj) {

   if (obj.innerHTML === "YES") {
       obj.innerHTML = "NO";
   }
   else {
      obj.innerHTML = "YES";
   }
  }
</script>

 <a href='javascript: void(0);' onclick="change_text(this)">YES</a>
 <a href='javascript: void(0);' onclick="change_text(this)">NO</a> 
 <a href='javascript: void(0);' onclick="change_text(this)">YES</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The elements on a page can not have same id. Here you are having same ids `id="toggle_button"` for all the three elements

Try this

**HTML**

```
<a href='javascript: void(0);' onclick="change_text(this)">YES</a>
 <a href='javascript: void(0);' onclick="change_text(this)">NO</a> 
 <a href='javascript: void(0);' onclick="change_text(this)">YES</a>
```

**Here is Javascript**

```
function change_text(btn) {
        if (btn.innerHTML === "YES") {
            btn.innerHTML = "NO";
        }
        else {
            btn.innerHTML = "YES";
        }
    }
```

The working [FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/uQprL/).

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below answer

```
function changeText(idElement) {
var element = document.getElementById('element' + idElement);
if (idElement === 1 || idElement === 2) {
    if (element.innerHTML === 'Read More...') element.innerHTML = 'Close';
    else {
        element.innerHTML = 'Read More...';
    }
}
}
```

and lived demo is http://jsfiddle.net/UfVAH/

Answer (score -2):

Use `this` keyword to get current element object in javascript.

Try this :

**HTML:**

```
<a href='javascript:void(0)'><p class="toggle_button" onclick="change_text(this)">YES</p></a>
<a href='javascript:void(0)'><p class="toggle_button" onclick="change_text(this)">NO</p></a> 
<a href='javascript:void(0)'><p class="toggle_button" onclick="change_text(this)">YES</p></a>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function change_text(Object) {
        if (Object.innerHTML === "YES") {
            Object.innerHTML = "NO";
        }
        else {
            Object.innerHTML = "YES";
        }
    }
```

[Try in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SDzcZ/)

Comment: @radhikadev, please don't use this. This is obtrusive JavaScript and goes against best practices.

Comment: Yes, you are right but in some scenario it must save some line of code.

Comment: @Down-voter: I did't understand, why down vote here?